# Second player gets stuck while joining

Tags: unity, c#, photon

I get this error message on the console whenever I try to make the second player join.

> Failed to find a `PhotonView` with `ID=2` for incoming `OwnershipUpdate` event (`newOwnerActorNumber=1`), `sender=1`. If you load scenes, make sure to pause the message queue.